# List Expiry Date Reminder

Tags: 2007, list, alert

I have a Sharepoint 2007 **Announcement List** which have an Expiry Date for every Item ..

I have really tried too much in this, but I came up short. I want to send an alert when an Item or Announcement when it Expires (on Expiry Date). Is there is anyway I can do it, cause it is not in the Alert options provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible OOB. You can do it by writing custom code either in a timerjob or a workflow, which will look for expired announcements and send a mail to the intended users.

Comment: Here are the steps for the timerjob: Look for the announcement which are going to expire today (Use CAML Query). Send a mail (SPUtility.SendMail) to the intentded users about the item getting expired. Finally schedule the job to run daily. However, if you are not comfortable with Timer jobs, create a console application with above logic and schedule it to run daily using task scheduler.

Comment: Salam 3alaikom, Can I do the Seps mentioned Using this Tool : http://sptimerjobadmin.codeplex.com/

Comment: I haven't used this tool, so can't comment on that. However, you can find following links useful:http://ajaxme.blogspot.in/2010/10/how-to-create-deploy-sharepoint-2007.html    http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/CreatingCustomSharePointTimerJobs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look in the document retention section here:
http://www.martinhatch.com/2008/08/how-to-handle-document-retention-and.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, That was helpful. I'll take a deep look into it and tell you about any progress.